# A rigorous meaning of "induced measure"?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

In my readings I often come across terms like "induced measure" or "induced Lebesgue measure". For example:

> $$\int_{\mathbb{B}^n}u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j}\;dx = \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}uv\frac{x_j}{|x|}\;d\sigma - \int_{\mathbb{B}^n}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}\;dx$$ where $d\sigma$ denotes the *induced Lebesgue measure* on the sphere.

Unfortunately though, I've never really seen anyone give a ***rigorous definition*** to this phrase. Sure, in the above example, we understand how to parametrize the $n$ ball, $\mathbb{B}^n$, and the $n-1$ sphere, $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, and so the integrals are easy to compute and not very confusing. Sometimes, however, it appears in the context of a general hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (say $\Sigma$, with integrals involving $d\Sigma$), or when integrating over a subset (submanifold) of some higher-dimensional  space.

In a completely general setting like this, I am at a little bit of a loss when it comes to understanding  how these separate "surface" measures or "induced" measures are really defined, when I'm lacking an explicit parametrization.

---

It also doesn't help that traditional vector calculus classes seem to always fall short of doing anything past 3 dimensions. For example, I've never seen a class teach its students how to carry out a (2-D) surface integral in anything except $\mathbb{R}^3$; so they would have no idea how to go about finding the surface area of, say a [Clifford Torus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_torus) in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

And in general, I've never seen them address a general technique for integrating over an $n$-dimensional body, embedded in $n<m$-dimensional space. It seems like everything they're taught is in terms of the cross product, which fails to be of any use in $\mathbb{R}^{n>3}$.

---

Now I realize that at least some of the hypersurface examples from calculus, that I've mentioned above, can be addressed using the generalized Stokes' theorem: $\int_{D}\text{d}\omega = \int_{\partial D}\omega$. But it seems to me that when we are getting to the realm of measure theory, higher-level analysis, and Riemannian geometry, the word "induced" is probably thrown around for a good reason. Let me clarify what I mean:

- If we are on a Riemannian manifold $M$, then its metric $g$ defines a volume element for the the manifold, $dV_g = \sqrt{\det g}\;dV$, where $dV$ is the Euclidean measure for your coordinate patch in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If we then consider an immersed submanifold $N\hookrightarrow M$, we have a rigourous definition for the [induced metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Induced_metric) that $N$ inherits from $M$.
- If we have a topological space $(X,\tau)$, then it [induces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_topology) a subspace topology on any subset $Y\subset X$, $\tau_Y = \{Y\cap U : U\in\tau\}$. Similarly for any subset $Y\subset X$ of a $\sigma$-algebra $(X,\Sigma)$, we have the sub-$\sigma$-algebra $(Y,\Sigma_Y), \Sigma_Y = \{Y\cap A : A\in\Sigma\}$.

In these settings, the word "**induced**" has a very specific meaning, and essentially boils down to the idea of a subset inheriting some sort of property from a larger set it belongs to. So it would make sense that there should be some concrete way of having a *measure space* induce some kind of measure on a subset of itself.

At first glance, since a measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ can give rise to a sub-$\sigma$-algebra (as mentioned above) then you might want to simply take the restriction of $\mu$ to these subsets in $\Sigma_Y$. But the problem is that any subset $E$, without full dimension, will of course have measure zero, $\mu(E)=0$. So this would make for a lousy way to define integration over this subset.

So maybe we only concern ourselves with Riemannian manifolds, and just define the *induced measure* as the one that arrises from the *induced metric* of some parent manifold. But this seems limiting for a couple reasons:

1. Integration is now limited to Riemannian manifolds, and no longer over a general measure space. For example, while integration with respect to the counting measure makes sense over $\mathbb{N}$, I can't see any way to interpret this as integration over a Riemannian manifold; and so the question of how the counting measure "induces" another measure would be meaningless.
2. If we consider a (smooth) subset $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, we can build a measure space on $S$ from scratch, similar to how we build the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in measure theory. My question then is: are we always able to realize integration (with respect to this measure) over $S$ as integration with respect to some induced metric, by considering $S\subset M$, for some manifold $(M,g)$?

To me, a measure (and anything that it induces) should be in the spirit of measurable sets, and not be restricted to differential manifolds. The Lebesgue measure $\mu$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ gives us the volume of the unit ball as $\frac{4}{3}\pi$; shouldn't $\mu$ **induce** a measure on $\mathbb{S}^2$, to give us $4\pi$ surface area? And whatever method we choose, shouldn't it apply to abstract measures as well, not just Lebesgue measure?

Comment: After checking [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83260/29816) in physics, I wanted to find a mathematical reference for such a question. I have found one in "A course on integration, Nicolas Lerner" (2014), §5.5 p.238. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1518227/92038) is another approach.

Comment: Thank you. That's an interesting reference.

Comment: Another interesting reference: "Éléments de distributions et d’équations aux dérivées partielles" (Dunodn 2002) by Claude Zuily, (2.11), (2.16) p.42 'till p.44: the measure on the boundary of a domain $\omega$ is obtained as the weak derivative of the characteristic function $\chi_{\Omega}$. cf. also (2.19) p.45, when the boundary is given as the graph of a function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word "induced" does not always refer to "a subset inheriting some sort of property from a larger set it belongs to". It also refers to one kind of structure defining another kind of structure on the same set. Examples:

- norm induced by an inner product
- metric induced by a norm
- topology induced by a metric

All of these can refer to the same underlying set, e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In the context of your quote at the beginning, I would interpret "induced" as in

> measure induced by Riemannian metric [by means of the volume form].

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/60554) is a usage example from MathOverflow.

---

But if you want to induce the measure on $S^2$ coming from the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^3$, I can suggest some approaches:

1. Consider the *Hausdorff measure* $\mathcal H^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Its restriction to  $S^2$ is the surface measure.
2. Given $A\subset S^2$, define the [upper] *Minkowski content* of $A$ as 
   $$m^*(A) =  \limsup_{r\to 0} \frac{\mu(A_r)}{2r}\quad \text{where } A_r=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3 : \operatorname{dist} (x,A)\le r\} $$ 
   For nice sets this is the same as surface area; unfortunately for uglier sets countable additivity fails. Also, the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are different in general.
3. Fix the subadditivity issue in #2 by defining the [upper] packing measure of $A$ as 
   $$\inf\left\{ \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} m^*(A_j) : \bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} A_j = A\right\}$$ 
   This is an ugly definition, but it  has countable sub-additivity built-in. Since the resulting  measure is invariant under isometries of $S^2$, it is in fact the surface area.

Comment: Thanks. The Minkowski content definition is along the lines of what I was looking for; it's also good to know that this definition has some important limitations.

The stuff in the Overflow link was also very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: In this answer, $\mu$ refers to the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^3$, right?