# The Change-of-Variable Theorem for Lebesgue Integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral, change-of-variable

My question concerns an application of the standard integration by substitution tecnique. I am aware of the following result.

Let $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be an open set and $\varphi \colon V \mapsto \mathbb{R}^d$ be a one-to-one $\mathcal{C}^1(V)$ mapping with non-vanishing Jacobian $J_\varphi$. Then it holds
$$
\int_{\varphi (V)} h d\lambda_d = \int_V (h \circ \varphi) \lvert J_\varphi \rvert d\lambda_d
$$
for a continuous function $h$.

My question is the follwing. Can we apply a similar technique, if $\varphi$ is a linear injective function of the form $\varphi \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, with $m \neq n$? Note that in this case, the Jacobian $J_\varphi$ is simply its corresponding matrix, which is non-square.

Comment: In principle you can, but you have to be careful with the meaasures. The measure on $\varphi(V)$ must be an appropriate $n$-dimensional measure. Since you assume $\varphi$ is injective and linear, it follows that $m>n$. In that case, 
the $m$-dimensional measure vanishes on any $n$-dimensional subset.

Comment: Take a case of $m=3$, $n=2$, on the left you basically want to integrate something over a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. 3D Lebesgue measure will not give you anything non-trivial. There are ways to induce a measure on the plane from a measure in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but they are more involved than mere change of variables with a Jacobian factor, see [A rigorous meaning of “induced measure”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1194313/152568)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What can we say about the case of $\varphi$ not being injective?